# Set authentication user password on windows openvpn server

Tags: windows, authentication, openvpn

Is it possible to set authentication with USERNAME/PASSWORD on openvpn WINDOWS server? I only found a guide for Linux but obviously it does not work on Windows.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible, on OpenVpn Windows server you can only set cert authentication